# Unable to find a specification for `boost-for-react-native` depended upon by `Folly`

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, xcode, react-native

I have one project in react native, i am trying to run the project in ios, but i am getting the next error (Unable to find a specification for `boost-for-react-native` depended upon by `Folly`)

***Detail***

```
test@test ios % pod install
Detected React Native module pods for RNCMaskedView, RNFS, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNScreens, ReactNativeLocalization, get-random-values-polypony, react-native-dynatrace, react-native-safe-area-context, and react-native-text-input-mask
/Users/test/.cocoapods/repos-art/biocatch-cocoapods/.artpodrc
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `BigNumber` from `https://github.com/cs-thiago-lioy/Swift-Big-Integer.git`
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
/Users/OCE00524/.cocoapods/repos-art/biocatch-cocoapods/.artpodrc
[!] Unable to find a specification for `boost-for-react-native` depended upon by `Folly`
You have either:
* out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
* mistyped the name or version.
* not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

The react native version is 0.63

Answer (score 0):

I found the next steps, it worked me well

- Delete the project.
- Delete the next folder (cd /Users/test/.cocoapods)
- Clone the project again.
- Open one terminal.
- Open path folder in the terminal ( cd )
- Execute npm i
- Go the ios folder
- Finally execute pod install